# The index of reducibility of $(0)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I had posted this problem on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270217/the-index-of-reducibility-of-0), but I get no answer until now. Hopefully, I could recieve some hints at there.

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring and $M$ is a $(R,\mathfrak{m})$-module such that $l_{R}(M)<\infty$. Prove that there is an irredundant decomposition $$(0)=N_{1}\cap N_{2}\cap \cdots \cap N_{n}$$ of $(0)$ in $M$ such that each $N_{i}$ is an irreducible $R$-submodule of $M$ and $n=l_{R}((0):_{M} \mathfrak{m})$.

I got stuck at proving $n=l_{R}((0):_{M} \mathfrak{m})$ , so it is very grateful to me when you give me answer.

Comment: As it should be clear to you, a question of this kind is of high level (upper undergraduate or graduate level), and thus you should *at least* explain your symbols, in particular what being a $\;R,\mathcal m)\,-$ modules means. Perhaps is $\;R\;$ a local ring and that's its maximal ideal, or what?

Comment: Yes, I mean $R$ is a local ring,